# Check if both column and table exist and run queries based on the result

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

I am trying to run some SQL queries on Oracle database, but before running the query I need to check if both table and column exists. If table exists and column does not exist, then run another query:

```
if table `testtable` exists and if table has column `testcolumn`
    Run a SQL which returns the result 
else if table `testtable` exists but column `testcolumn` not present
    Run a different sql which also returns the result 
else
    print some defined string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DECLARE
  nCount  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nCount
    FROM USER_TAB_COLS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTTABLE' AND
          COLUMN_NAME = 'TESTCOLUMN';

  IF nCount > 0 THEN
    -- Run a SQL which returns the result 
  ELSE
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM USER_TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTTABLE';

    IF nCount > 0 THEN
      Run a different sql which also returns the result 
    ELSE
      print some defined string
 END;
```

You'll have to add code to run whatever SQL you're trying to run, and to print whatever message you need.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option - check contents of `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and - depending on what you find - use refcursor in order to return the result.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_cnt number;
  5    cur_r sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    -- 1st test - this one fails
  8    select count(*)
  9      into l_cnt
 10      from user_tab_columns
 11      where table_name = 'EMP'
 12        and column_name = 'DOES_NOT_EXIST';
 13
 14    if l_cnt > 0 then
 15       open cur_r for select ename, job, sal from emp;
 16    end if;
 17
 18    -- 2nd test - this one is OK
 19    select count(*)
 20      into l_cnt
 21      from user_tab_columns
 22      where table_name = 'DEPT'
 23        and column_name = 'DEPTNO';
 24
 25    if l_cnt > 0 then
 26       open cur_r for select dname, loc from dept;
 27    end if;
 28
 29    return cur_r;
 30  end;
 31  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          LOC
-------------- -------------
ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
RESEARCH       DALLAS
SALES          CHICAGO
OPERATIONS     BOSTON


SQL>
```

It has to be some kind of a *dynamic* code because you can't just write a *static* `SELECT` statement that selects non-existent columns as you'd get `ORA-00904: "DOES_NOT_EXIST": invalid identifier` error.